# How to run an infinite job/process in elixir?

Tags: elixir

I'm trying to create an application without frameworks to run a background job infinitely.

I have set up an empty `mix` project and it has following files:

```elixir
# lib/application.ex
defmodule Foo.Application do
  use Application

  @impl true
  def start(_type, _args) do
    children = [
      {Foo.Counter, []}
    ]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
  end
end
```

```elixir
# lib/counter.ex
defmodule Foo.Counter do
  use GenServer

  @time_interval_ms 1000

  def start_link(_) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, 0)
  end

  @impl true
  def init(counter) do
    Process.send_after(self(), :increment, @time_interval_ms)
    {:ok, counter}
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_info(:increment, counter) do
    Process.send_after(self(), :increment, @time_interval_ms)
    IO.puts(counter)
    {:noreply, counter+1}
  end
end
```

`applications` in my `mix.exs` looks as follows:

```elixir
def application do
    [
      mod: {Foo.Application, []},
      extra_applications: [:logger]
    ]
end
```

Though, when I run `mix run` I don't get anything:

```
$ mix run
$
```

Yet when I run `iex -S mix` I can see that counter is working on the background:

```
$ iex -S mix
Erlang/OTP 24 [erts-12.1] [source] [64-bit] [smp:12:12] [ds:12:12:10] [async-threads:1] [jit]

Interactive Elixir (1.12.2) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> 0
1
2
3
```

How can I make so that `mix run` does not exit and continues to run infinitely?

Comment: Have you tried `mix run --no-halt`?
--no-halt - does not halt the system after running the command

Comment: Thank you so much @sabiwara, it does the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `mix run --ho-halt` instead of `mix run` if you want to keep the application running after the command finishes execution.

[All `mix run` options](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Tasks.Run.html#module-command-line-options).

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct with a greeny on the top-left side of the answer.